# pushing dynamic data to stacked percentage column in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to plot some data using stacked percentage column. But the data is dynamic and the data is obtained via ajax.

Here is an example of one of the ajax responses-

X-axis categories-

```
Array
(
    [ID0] => 2013/07/22
    [ID1] => 2013/07/23
    [ID2] => 2013/07/24
    [ID3] => 2013/07/25
)
```

series data and name-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID1] => 5
            [ID3] => 2
            [ID4] => 1
            [ID5] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID1] => 5
            [ID3] => 1
            [ID4] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID1] => 5
            [ID2] => 1
            [ID3] => 2
            [ID4] => 3
            [ID5] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID1] => 6
            [ID2] => 3
            [ID4] => 1
            [ID5] => 1
        )

)
```

And this is what I want- http://jsfiddle.net/NF9Yp/

Comment: Take look at the article about preprocessing data http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing

Comment: @RicardoLohmann I've made too many changes to edit this question, so I asked a new question. here it is- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959707/highcharts-pushing-json-data-to-stacked-percentage-column

Answer (score 0):

you can generate categories and series array from server side. then your ajax function as below. jsondata returns from server in Json format. set options categories and series values from jsondata's properties.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: callbackUrl,            
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (jsondata) {
var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: jsondata.categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'percent'
            }
        },
            series: jsonData.series
    };
    $('#container').highcharts(options);
        },
        error: showAjaxError
    })
```